# MySQL 8 - Error log into Syslog

Tags: mysql, debian, syslog

i'am trying to switch /var/log/mysql/error.log into syslog in MySQL 8. Reason is compatibility with our monitoring for parse, maybe not that clean, but it does the job. I had no problem with this on mysql <=5.7

I followed man page https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/error-log-syslog.html and it start showing some start/stop messages, but still not quite I want to accomplished.

The log file /var/log/mysql/error.log is still the only log which show errors like these, which I would like to have in `syslog`:

```
2018-08-10T13:53:50.927165Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2018-08-10T13:54:06.285066Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
```

I tried a lot of thing by now, even start mysqld_safe as root.

Please dont advise adding `syslog` under `[mysqld]`, this setting is removed in 8.0.13 (next build)

In cnf I have only add `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`:

```
log_error_services  = 'log_sink_syseventlog'
```

Mysql version is `mysql-community-server 8.0.12-1debian9`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If this is debian 9 its running `systemd` right? So the output would be going to the journal (The mysqld stderr will be going to the journal). Look at `/proc/{mysqldpid}/fd` and look where stdout/stderror go to. If so, `journalctl` should be able to access the mysql error log.

Comment: It is debian 9, but it does not run systemd.

Comment: `/proc/{mysqldpid}/fd` and looking at the 1 and 2 symlinks is where your error log is.